# Chat bots are dead, looks like being blocked by something on the server side

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, robots, web-sockets

For over an hour now, Smoke Detector and other bots in MSE chat are dead and can't post in that chat anymore.

The problem appears to be some breaking change on SE side, though I don't have access to logs for more details.

Can the change please be reverted/fixed so bots can live and prosper again?

Comment: Not just MSE chat. Smokey has gone silent in SOVCR, too. And SOBotics, too - which is kinda, sorta a significant issue for a room *dedicated* to bots. :(

Comment: @AdrianMole yeah but other bots appear to not be fully dead like Smokey, though not sure if that's due to how they're built or due to the chat domain being less broken.

Comment: Looks like they fixed it (or, at least un-broke it).

Comment: @AdrianMole true, I'll wait for a while for official response.

Comment: Something something, redeploy websocket for Chat... something something... balpha to the rescue, something something whatever. Maybe someday someone else will explain what happened but... that's the best I can do. :P

Answer (score 20):

When connecting to any chatroom, the websocket connection that's meant to be formed immediately errors out. In the console, I see:

> master-chat.js?v=8e20450acb97:7 WebSocket connection to 'wss://chat.sockets.stackexchange.com/events/11540/fd47627c167143c4a19fd9448d67dd79?l=139686844' failed:

Along with a link to some minified JS. "11540" is the ID of the chatroom I'm attempting to connect to.

SmokeDetector, specifically, [relies on a Websocket connection in order to monitor for chat commands](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62828872#62828872). For the moment, Smokey is running in output-only mode and isn't watching for chat messages, which is allowing it to continue running at least in Charcoal HQ.

In any case, there's certainly a problem with SE's chat websocket. This answer is just here to supply that information.

Comment: Awesome, hopefully SE devs will wake up soon and this might help them fix the issue.

Answer (score 7):

As explained in [this comment by SE staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386001/chat-bots-are-dead-looks-like-being-blocked-by-something-on-the-server-side#comment1287136_386001), the developers redeployed websockets for chat, which caused the websocket connections in chat to fail.

balpha was called for the rescue and saved the <s>day</s> bots.

This answer is hopefully temporary placeholder until balpha will post more details. :)

Comment: It *did* affect ordinary users. It was broken for all uses of the chat WebSocket, including normal webpage access. However, the SE chat client falls back to polling for new messages (I'm not recalling how often) instead of using the WebSocket. It has that mode available because it uses such polling when a chat room is viewed by a user who isn't logged in (you can test with a private tab/window), as opening the WebSocket requires authentication to the user's account. Bots could, but generally don't use, a similar polling fallback, because they don't need it, except for major SE breakage.

Comment: @Makyen I see,  thanks. I didn't notice any change in my chat experience, so assumed it wasn't affected.